# Can I use conditional formatting in an Excel PivotTable to format cells based on specific fields?

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, microsoft-excel-2016, pivot-table, conditional-formatting

I have the results of numerous tests run on several sub-samples. Many sub-samples make up a sample. Between 5 and 10 samples make up a lot, and I have five lots I'm trying to analyze.

Each one of the aforementioned tests has an associated set of specifications; in other words, there are definite "wrong answers". In order to look for trends in the data, I've placed all my data into a PivotTable. The problem is that I've now got over 28,000 different distinct data points.

In an effort to aid my search, I want the "wrong answers" to be formatted differently than the "right answers". At the same time, I'm not sure how I'm going to spot trends, so I'm going to be fiddling with this thing a lot, looking for information. I want the formatting to follow the cells based on their fields. I have yet to figure out a way to do this. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that conditional formatting of over 28,000 distinct data points will only be a superficial measure. But yes, you can use conditional formatting in a pivot table. If you format the Values area, you will see a few radio buttons on the dialog where you can specify what context the format should be applied to

[image]

You may get a lot more traction on your data, though, if you pull it into Power Query (Get & Transform on the Data ribbon) and set a few helper columns to classify your data into good, bad or evil. Then, you can use pivot tables with slicers and filters to get your data under control.

Comment: It's more that I know where to look, but not which specific values are erroneous; I just want to make them stand out. Also, I'm unfamiliar with Power Query; I'll have to investigate that further. Thank you!

Comment: I just tried this, using the "All cells showing X values for Y and Z", but that applies the rule to all the cells. I forgot to mention, but each sub-sample has different structures; the range of "correct" answers depends on the test and the structure. So all of X test on Y structure will have the same correct range across all samples and lots, but X test on Z structures will have a different correct range that will be the same across all samples across all lots. If that makes any sense...

Comment: Basically, I tried asking a more subjective question earlier and was shot down, as is SE's way. I don't know the best way to look at this data to look for trends, etc. Do you have suggestions for additional ways to do so that may be helpful? I'm looking into Power Query right now.

Comment: You could use worksheet cells that reference the pivot table and evaluate if a row is good, bad or ugly. If the pivot table changes the number of rows or rows in a category when it is refreshed, that would need to be updated, though. Power Query might be a better option because you can put the condition check right into the data query and it can be refreshed when the source data changes.